# Autobahn 0.9.5 (AMD) - Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: websocket, durandal, durandal-2.0, autobahn, autobahnws

I'm trying to implement **[autobahn 0.9.5](https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.js)** on my SPA project using *DurandalJS*.

```
        var ab = require('autobahn');

        live = new ab.Connection(
        {
            url: 'ws://localhost:8080',
            realm: 'realm1'
        });

        live.onopen = function(session, details)
        {
            console.log('Autobahn open successfully!', session);
        };

        live.onclose = function(reason, details)
        {
            console.log('Autobahn connection lost', reason + ' - ' + details);
        };

        live.open();
```

i received an error on firefox and chrome browser

Firefox:

```
 InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object
 websocket.close(code, reason);
```

Chrome:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received
```

I have no idea what happened..

**BEFORE I STARTED WITH** - **autobahn 0.9.5**

I have write simple test on **test.html** to see if everything setup in backend is correct.
But on this test i currently used **autobahn 0.8.2**

**test.html**

```
<script src="http://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/autobahn.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var conn = new ab.Session(

        // Websocket host
        'ws://localhost:8080',

        // Callback on connection established
        function() {
            // Once connect, subscribe to channel
            conn.subscribe('3', function(topic, data) {
                console.log(topic, data);              
            });
        },

        // Callback on connection close
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },

        // Additional AB parameters
        {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );
</script>
```

This test working perfectly as what i need, but after I try to implement it inside real project, I can't make **autobahn 0.8.2** loaded using requireJS, It keep give me an error ***ab not defined.***

I don't really understand what is happening, according of [autobahn getting started](http://autobahn.ws/js/gettingstarted.html), it should work.

and here is how I define it on main.js (requirejs paths and shim config)

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
      'autobahn'          : 'https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.min',
      'when'              : 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/when/2.7.1/when'
  },
  shim: {
     'autobahn': {
         deps: ['when']
     }
  }
});
```

Hopefully somebody can help me, I really love to make it working !

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Hey, what was the issue that was causing the two errors? I'm writing an app with RatchetPHP and I have the same two errors showing up when using latest Autobahn and playing with their 'getting sarted', but the app seems to be working fine with the 0.8.2 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably late, but for further reference.

This is probably not a complete answer to SO question.

First of all, everything should be written either for AutobahnJS v0.8.2 (which supports WAMPv1) or for AutobahnJS v0.9.5 (WAMPv2).

Check API documentation.

**WAMP v1**

- [**AutobahnJS v0.8.2 API** - http://autobahn.ws/js/reference_wampv1.html](http://autobahn.ws/js/reference_wampv1.html)
- it loads from http://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/autobahn.js
- global variable for autobahn is **ab**
- connecting with `var conn = new ab.Session(wuri, onOpenCallback, onCloseCallback, options);`

**WAMP v2**

- [**AutobahnJS v0.9.5 API** - http://autobahn.ws/js/reference.html](http://autobahn.ws/js/reference.html)
- it loads from https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.min.jgz
- global variable for autobahn is **autobahn**
- connecting with `new autobahn.Connection({url: wuri, realm: yourRealm});`

Comment: Thanks @MrW, I've successfully make it work! Things causes I was unable to connect (with error returned) is something we missed on backend stuff. So, i vote you up for a good reference!

Comment: Thank you! That is helped a lot for clear stuff for my self also, after a lot of reading.